# Should questions be asking for random numbers

Tags: discussion

As seen in [this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11475/64505) and [this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11358/64505) in the sandbox, some questions ask for pseudorandom numbers to be applied in a mathematical operation. Frequently, these questions are trivial mathematical operations for which the only difference is the operations use a pseudorandom number. Should generation of pseudorandom numbers be allowed as a requirement for a challenge?

Comment: Just because some challenges don't use randomness in a proper manner doesn't mean there aren't challenges that do.

Comment: Why do you think shouldn't the generation of pseudorandom numbers *not* be allowed under the current rules?

Comment: Maybe a better question here might be "If a challenge is identical to another, but replaces an operand with a random value, should they be considered duplicates?" In a similar vein we usually close challenges as duplicates which fix one of the operands to a specific value.

Answer (score 4):

## Varies by the question.

Some questions use psuedorandom numbers, and theres a [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) tag for that.

Since there is no rules which restricts them, it will be allowed.

*However*, Trivial ones, like what you posted, are discouraged, and will most likely be disliked or flagged. (by any reason, most likely duplicates or not clear)

If they don't violate other rules, questions containing psuedorandom numbers are fine.